# Mobile safari: From fullscreen page, how to open a page in a normal safari window?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

The title has it all: My page runs in full screen mode (cf. using an icon on the springboard); When I click a link to an external page, I would like to have it open in the normal safari application, not the full screen instance.
How can this be done?

I expected window.open('url', '_blank') to do the trick, but it doesnt.

Thanks!

Edit: code snippet:

```
        $('#gotoWebsitePlaceholder').selectable({

            start: function(){

                window.open('http://www. ... .com', "_blank");
            }
        }).hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using an anchor tag? My experience is that the default action is to open the href target in the Safari app. I.E., if I didn't cancel the default action via javascript, my app would shift out of the FS app. Can you post a code snippet?

Comment: Hey, just put the code snippet. It's a div made selectable by jqueryUI. Once clicked, it opens the url. But it remains in FS mode.

Comment: Can you do this in your HTML? `<a href="http://www. ... .com"><div id="gotoWebsitePlaceholder">...</div></a>` I believe that the anchor will do what you want by default. (I also understand that it's OK to put a DIV inside an Anchor in HTML 5. If that's not correct, you could change the div to a span and style it to display as a block).

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that Safari will remain in fullScreen when executing window.open(myURL) or this.location = myURL. However if your url is called using click it will exit fullScreen mode.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this piece of js (tested in ipad with iOS 5.1.1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('a').click(function() {
      if (($(this).attr("target")!="_blank")){
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        return false;
      }
  });
```

So only the links with target="_blank" will open in safari.